# Docker mongodb config file

Tags: mongodb, docker

There is a way to link `/data/db` directory of the container to your localhost. But I can not find anything about configuration. How to link `/etc/mongo.conf` to anything from my local file system. Or maybe some other approach is used. Please share your experience.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you run docker container using this:

```
docker run -d -v /var/lib/mongo:/data/db \ 
-v /home/user/mongo.conf:/etc/mongo.conf -p port:port image_name
```

`/var/lib/mongo` is a host's mongo folder.

`/data/db` is a folder in docker container.

Comment: is it possible to map files with `-v` flag?

Comment: I get permission error when reading mapped file mongo.conf from inside the running container. Changign permissions (chmod 777) does not help.

Comment: can you share `dockerfile` file ?

Comment: The problem is /etc/mongo.conf is not available with the one in docker hub now but there is mongo.conf.orig file

Answer (score 35):

I'm using the mongodb 3.4 official docker image.  Since the mongod doesn't read a config file by default, this is how I start the mongod service:

```
docker run -d --name mongodb-test -p 37017:27017 \
 -v /home/sa/data/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
 -v /home/sa/data/db:/data/db mongo --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

removing -d will show you the initialization of the container

Using a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
 mongodb_server:
    container_name: mongodb_server
    image: mongo:3.4
    env_file: './dev.env'
    command:
        - '--auth'
        - '-f'
        - '/etc/mongod.conf'
    volumes:
        - '/home/sa/data/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf'
        - '/home/sa/data/db:/data/db'
    ports:
        - '37017:27017'
```

then

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: I believe in your command section it should read '/etc/mongod.conf'.

Answer (score 3):

I merely wanted to know the command used to specify a config for mongo through the `docker run` command.

First you want to specify the volume flag with `-v` to map a file or directory from the host to the container. So if you had a config file located at `/home/ubuntu/` and wanted to place it within the `/etc/` folder of the container you would specify it with the following:

`-v /home/ubuntu/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf`

Then specify the command for mongo to read the config file after the image like so:

`mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf`

If you put it all together, you'll get something like this:

```
docker run -d --net="host" --name mongo-host -v /home/ubuntu/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I should use MongoDb with VERSION:3.0.1

Now : 2016-09-13 17:42:06

---

That is what I found:

```
#first step: run mongo 3.0.1 without conf
docker run --name testmongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:3.0.1

#sec step: 
docker exec -it testmongo cat /entrypoint.sh                                                                                        

#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- mongod "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'mongod' ]; then
    chown -R mongodb /data/db

    numa='numactl --interleave=all'
    if $numa true &> /dev/null; then
        set -- $numa "$@"
    fi

    exec gosu mongodb "$@" 
fi

exec "$@"
```

I find that there are two ways to start a mongod service.
What I try:

```
  docker run --name mongo -d -v your/host/dir:/container/dir mongo:3.0.1  -f /container/dir/mongod.conf
```

- the last `-f` is the mongod parameter, you can also use `--config` instead.
- make sure the path like `your/host/dir` exists and the file `mongod.conf` in it.

Comment: `-f` gives the error `unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'docker start --help'.`

Comment: Did you use `docker run` ? the error shows like you use the `docker start` indeed. @AvindraGoolcharan